# Loop over response objects based on condition angular 5

Tags: angular5, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a rest response which i want to loop over but based on condition, here's my response:

```
{
    "veichleType": "SUV",
    "veichleBrand": "BMW",
    "veichleModels": [{
            "veichleModel": "M3",
            "property1": "value",
            "property2": "value",
            "property3": "value"
        },
        {
            "veichleModel": "M1",
            "property": "value",
            "property2": "value",
            "property3": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want in the UI to show only one object based on veichleModel if user searched by M3 then display that object response in the table, else show M1.

```
<table>
<thead>
headings here
</thead>
<tbody *ngIf='serviceResponse.veichleModels'>
<tr *ngFor="let veichleModel of serviceResponse.veichleModels">
<td>{{veichleModels.property1}}</td>
<td>{{veichleModels.property2}}</td>
<td>{{veichleModels.property3}}</td>        
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things here :

1. Add some variable to store the selected model `M1` or `M3`
2. Add condition inside loop to display respective object properties (Make use of `ng-container`)

Doing so, you can scale your array to 100 or more objects

template

```
<tbody *ngIf='serviceResponse.veichleModels'>
        <tr *ngFor="let veichle of serviceResponse.veichleModels">
            <ng-container *ngIf="veichle.veichleModel == selected">
                <td>{{veichle.property1}}</td>
                <td>{{veichle.property2}}</td>
                <td>{{veichle.property3}}</td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

ts file

```
export class AppComponent  {
  selected = 'M1';
  serviceResponse = {"veichleModels": [{
            "veichleModel": "M3",
            "property1": "M3val1",
            "property2": "M3val2",
            "property3": "M3val3"
        },
        {
            "veichleModel": "M1",
            "property1": "M1val1",
            "property2": "M1val2",
            "property3": "M1val3"
        }
    ]}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i want to ask why shall I add the values and properties in the component? The response is from rest API with two object which I iterate over in the template, I just wanted to display one of the objects not the complete response based on the veichleModel

Comment: You can modify it as you want. And of course you can assign the dynamic data to `serviceResponse`. I just show how you can print the object properties based on certain condition. And that is your actual question. And in my answer i do display only one object whose condition match, not the entire response.